dummy features has almost the same effect as actual features
4 dummy random features (using np.random.randn) and 4 new real features (brough from some ideas) shows almost the same improvement.
In cross validation, 4 dummies increased PR_AUC by about 0.01 and the 4 real features increased PR_AUC by about 0.01.
Here are some characteristics of my data:

data size is about 700, 500 is training data.
Feature count(before adding the above) is 13.
Used autogluon for training
multiple data may come from a single sample.

What happened here? Should I reject to use the 4 new features?

Have you tested individual feature performance (information value) ? should these variables have predictability from a practical perspective ?
